# Handling Outside Clicks in Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I want a confirmation dialog to appear when I tap outside the dialog fragment, asking 'Are you sure you want to exit without saving?' When the user presses the 'Yes' button, I want the dialog fragment to close. Otherwise, if they dismiss the confirmation dialog, I want it to close, leaving the original dialog fragment open. The tricky part is that tapping outside the dialog fragment shouldn't close the fragment itself, but should trigger the confirmation dialog. How can I achieve this? Here's my Dialog Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ConfessAnswerFragment(
    private val onUpdateItem: (position: Int, updatedConfession: Confession) -> Unit,
    private val findItemById: (confessionId: String) -> Int
) : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentConfessAnswerBinding
    private lateinit var navRegister: FragmentNavigation
    private val viewModel: ConfessViewModel by viewModels()
    private var isAnswerButtonEnabled = false
    private var isEditAnswer: Boolean = false
    private var isAnswerFavorited: Boolean = false
    private lateinit var currentUserUid: String
    private lateinit var confessionId: String
    private lateinit var answerDate: String
    private lateinit var dialogHelper: DialogTemplate

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentConfessAnswerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        navRegister = activity as FragmentNavigation
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        confessionId = arguments?.getString("confessionId", "") ?: ""
        currentUserUid = arguments?.getString("currentUserUid", "") ?: ""
        answerDate = arguments?.getString("answerDate", "") ?: ""
        dialogHelper = DialogTemplate(requireContext())

        getConfession(confessionId)

        return binding.root
    }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        observeGetConfession()
        observeAddAnswer()
        observeFavorite()
        observeDeleteAnswer()
    }
...
```

Comment: That's not a good pratice show a dialog over another dialog. Why not just set Dialog.setCancelable(false) and/or Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to `onCreateView`

```
setOutsideTouchListener()
return binding.root
```

And simple example for Alert Dialog and handle dismisses

```
private fun showConfirmationDialog() {
    // It will listen for all touches.
    // We do not want it to be triggered when clicking the yes or no buttons in the AlertDialog.
    clearOutSideTouchListener()

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit without saving?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
            dismiss()
        }
        .setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.dismiss()

            //We have to activate it again.
            setOutsideTouchListener()
        }

    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

    dialog.show()
}
```

Outside touch listener

```
private fun setOutsideTouchListener() {
    val outsideTouchListener = View.OnTouchListener { _, _ ->
        showConfirmationDialog()
        true
    }
    dialog?.window?.decorView?.setOnTouchListener(outsideTouchListener)
}
```

clear touch listener

```
private fun clearOutSideTouchListener() {
    dialog?.window?.decorView?.setOnTouchListener(null)
}
```

Comment: I applied what you wrote to my code. Here, when I click inside the dialog fragment, it goes to the 'else' part, but it doesn't go to the 'if' part when I click outside. I couldn't manage to capture the outside clicks.

Comment: Actually, I waited for it to be resolved by overriding onCancel. But even though I deleted the onCancel super, I saw that it was dismissed anyway when I pressed the no button. . So I added a new solution. Can you try?

Comment: I also activated the 'setOutsideTouchListener' in 'dialog.setOnCancelListener', removed "    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)" and now it's working exactly as I wanted. Thank you for your help.